# :q will not let me exit vim

Tags: buffers, quit, nvi

[image]

When using nvi I have a file that I want to exit but everytime I use :q it just opens this thing and I can't exit out of it. Does anyone know what it is and how to get rid of it?

Note: this is nvi and not vim, so hasn't been caused by accidentally typing `q:` or by a mapping to `q:`.

Comment: The solutions in that thread don't work. <C-w> q just makes a smaller version of that windo popup.

Comment: this doesn't look like vim at all, how did you get here?

Comment: I'm using putty to ssh into a testing environment. I put the contents of a find command into a file named log and used vi log to open it. This is the result of trying to exit with :q.

Comment: `telnet users.deterlab.net` gives me `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2 FreeBSD-20161230` @Mass, so it's probably `nvi`, which is the default `vi` on FreeBSD.

Comment: That being said, it's not clear to me what exactly I'm looking at? Did you try pressing `<Esc><Esc>:q`? What are the *exact* steps to reproduce this?

Comment: What's your .exrc (or .nexrc)? Sounds like you have `set cedit=^M`. `:q<Esc>` in that situation will let you quit until you can fix your exrc. (And yeah, that's nvi.)

Comment: FWIW, I did *not* vote to close this as a duplicate. I voted for "unclear what you're asking" pending a response to Carpetsmoker and @Antony's queries.

Comment: I've re-closed it as "unclear what you're asking". It's clearly not a duplicate, but it's also not clear how to reproduce this. I'll be happy to re-open when the steps to reproduce are clearer.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker It says log: unmodified: line 1 at the very bottom as opposed to "log" 1L, 32C which is what it did before. Any attempts to escape cause the box at the bottom to popup. I'm not sure how this happened. I was trying to exit and I guess I pressed some wrong keys or keys out of order which causes this to happen.

Comment: @Antony I'm not exactly sure what .exrc is. It was most likely causes when I tried to exit and pressed some extra keys or keys in the incorrect order.

Comment: The command-line history is enabled with the `cedit` option, which is empty by default. AFAIK there is no other way to access the command-line history in nvi. The .exrc or .nexrc files are the configuration files for nvi. Look in your home dir. Alternatively commands to be run at startup can be set in the EXINIT or NEXINIT environment variables, so maybe check those as well.